# Fastest way to measure compression ratio of a string in Python3

Tags: string, python-3.x, lzma

I want to estimate Kolmogorov complexity of short strings (about one word long) by compressing them with LZMA and taking the compression ratio.

What's the most efficient way of doing it in Python3?

Comment: Umm, you do realize that compressing a short string _increases_ the amount of bits to specify it, because you need to include the decompression algorithm?

Comment: From wikipedia: `simply compress the string s with some method, implement the corresponding decompressor in the chosen language, concatenate the decompressor to the compressed string, and measure the length of the resulting string`.

Comment: @RishavKundu The question is about implementation, not theory.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**:

I am not sure if this is a good way to estimate the complexity of short strings, because to correctly compute the Kolmogorov (K-) complexity of a string we have to factor in the length of the program used to decompress the string. The length of the program (67k for xz 5.1.0 on my Debian laptop) will overwhelm short strings. Thus, the following program is closer to computing a K-complexity upper bound:

```
import lzma #For python 2.7 use backports.lzma

program_length = 67000

def lzma_compression_ratio(test_string):
    bytes_in = bytes(test_string,'utf-8')
    bytes_out = lzma.compress(bytes_in)
    lbi = len(bytes_in)
    lbo = len(bytes_out)+program_length
    ratio = lbo/lbi
    message = '%d bytes compressed to %d bytes, ratio %0.3f'%(lbi,lbo,ratio)
    print(message)
    return ratio

test_string = 'a man, a plan, a canal: panama'
lzma_compression_ratio(test_string)

for n in range(22,25):
    test_string = 'a'*(2**n)
    lzma_compression_ratio(test_string)
```

The output below shows that the compression ratio is over 2000 for a string of 30 a's, and falls below 0.01 for repeating strings of length 2^23. These are technically correct upper bounds on K-complexity, but clearly not useful for the short string. The program "print('a'*30)" has length 13, which gives a K-complexity upper bound of 0.43 (13/30) for the string 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'.

```
30 bytes compressed to 67024 bytes, ratio 2234.133
4194304 bytes compressed to 67395 bytes, ratio 0.016
8388608 bytes compressed to 68005 bytes, ratio 0.008
16777216 bytes compressed to 69225 bytes, ratio 0.004
```

**Original answer**:

@Superbest, this seems to work, but I don't know if it's the most efficient:

```
import lzma

def lzma_compression_ratio(test_string):
    c = lzma.LZMACompressor()
    bytes_in = bytes(test_string,'utf-8')
    bytes_out = c.compress(bytes_in)
    return len(bytes_out)/len(bytes_in)

test_string = 'a man, a plan, a canal: panama'
compression_ratio = lzma_compression_ratio(test_string)
print(compression_ratio)
```

Comment: What do you wrap `len(...)` in `float`?

Comment: Also if I duplicate the last 3 lines (effectively asking it to calculate the same string twice) it gives first 0.8 then 0.0.

Comment: @Superbest, `float` is because I'm a Python 2.7 user.

Comment: question is tagged `python-3.x`

Comment: @Superbest, thank you for the comments. The first was removal of the `float` casts--not necessary in python 3.x. The second one (different answers if you duplicate the function call) was fixed by moving the `LZMACompressor` instantiation into the function. I modified my answer to reflect these.

Comment: Seems like now `'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'` is calculates as 0.8, same as `'a man, a plan, a canal: panama'`.

Comment: That's very weird. I don't have an explanation, but it seems like it might lie in the LZMA compression. Since Kolmogorov complexity is uncomputable, the best we can do is compute upper bounds, which is what your approach does.

Comment: Oh, so you get it too, strange. In Python2 compression ratio works well enough as a proxy. Looks like in Python3 something magical happens with the byte counts, so it messes up. Also, re: "`'a'*4096` has length 15" - sure, but the 15 is calculated by you, a human. I want Python[3] to calculate it, so I don't have to message you every time my `complexity(s)` function is called :) .

Comment: You forget to include the size of the LZMA module, _that_ is the program actually performing the compression/decompression :p

Comment: @rishav, are you referring to my edit or the original post?

Comment: @rjonnal oh I'm sorry, you have accounted for the size of the decompressor in your 67k.

Comment: This is incorrect, for one, the compressed bytes are obtained with `bytes_out = c.flush()` in Python3, and second, it gives incorrect results for me in Python3.